# Ubuntu shows a black screen which only has a blinking cursor

Tags: boot, gui, system, grub-efi, recovery-mode

My computer is an IdeaPad 3 Slim 3.

- Intel Core i5
- Intel iRIS XE graphics
- Dual boot Ubuntu and Windows

The problem started after I created a bootable USB for cloning the image from another computer, however once I used that USB and started booting the system in IdeaPad 3, the OS in that USB is working but the Ubuntu in my IdeaPad is not functioning anymore which is just the beginning of my nightmare. I am sure that I didn't change anything such as EFI or data in Ubuntu, but the computer after showing the Ubuntu logo just outputs a black screen with a blinking cursor and I can't input anything.

[image: black screen with a blinking cursor]

I have tried all commands in Recovery mode including `dpkg` `fsck` grub, and they all said the process finished successfully, but none of them could fix my problem.

I even tried to change `GRUP_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` into `GRUP_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"`, but it didn't fix my system.

[image]